# Linear bounded operator from $L^p[0,1]$ to itself whose range consists of continuous functions.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, examples-counterexamples, lp-spaces, compact-operators

Let $T\colon \mathbb L^p[0,1]\to \mathbb L^p[0,1]$, $1<p<+\infty$, be a linear bounded operator such that $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ is contained in the space of continuous functions. It was shown in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3225845/if-tlp0-1-to-lp0-1-bounded-for-1-p-infty-with-continuous-image) that $T$ is a compact operator.

Some non trivial example of such $T$ can be given, for example kernel operators with appropriated conditions on the kernel. The question is 
whether there exists other example (maybe asking for a characterisation is too ambitious).

Comment: From your comment in the linked post, doesn't it suffice to consider operators from $L_p[0,1]$ to $C[0,1]$? This may help: Operators from $X$ to $C[0,1]$ are characterized by functions from $[0,1]$ to $X^*$ that are continuous when $X^*$ has the weak* topology (c.f. Dunford and Schwartz, *Linear Operators*, vol 1, Theorem VI.7.1).

Comment: Operator $f\mapsto \int_0^x f(t)dt$

Comment: Another examples: Fractional integrals of the form $(- \partial_{tt}^2 )^{-\beta}$ for any $\beta > 1/p$, by Morrey's Inequality.